# Converting PreOrder Traversal to Inorder

Tags: c++

I want to push data of the printPreOder function into the printInOrder function as parameters as for how I did to the root node. But it throws an error anytime I try to push the specific node to it or it shows no results after I run. The Whole program is about converting PreOrder traversal to InOrder Traversal

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <queue>
using namespace std;
struct Node
{
  string data;
  Node *left;
  Node *right;
  Node *none;
  Node *noode;
};
struct Node *createnode(string value)
{
  Node *newnode = new Node;
  newnode->data = value;
  newnode->left = NULL;
  newnode->right = NULL;
  return newnode;
}
void printLevelOrder(Node *node)
{
  if (node == NULL)
  {
    return;
  }

  queue <Node *> q;
  q.push(node);

  while (q.empty() == false)
  {
    Node *newnode = q.front();
    cout << newnode->data << " ";
    q.pop();

    if (newnode->left != NULL)
    {
      q.push(newnode->left);
    }

    if (newnode->right != NULL)
    {
      q.push(newnode->right);
    }
  }
}

void printPreOrder(Node *noode)
{
  if (noode == NULL)
  {
    return;
  }

  cout << noode->data << " ";
  printPreOrder(noode->left);
  printPreOrder(noode->right);
}
void printInOrder(Node *none)
{
  if (none == NULL)
  {
    return;
  }

  printInOrder(none->left);
  cout << none->data << " ";
  printInOrder(none->right);
}

int main()
{
  struct Node *root = createnode("3");
  root->left = createnode("7");
  root->right = createnode("8");
  root->left->left = createnode("10");
  root->left->right = createnode("12");
  cout << "\nLevel Order Traversal:\n";
  printLevelOrder(root);
  cout << "\nPreOrder Traversal:\n";
  printPreOrder(root);
  cout << "\nInOrder Traversal:\n";
  printInOrder(root->noode->data);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: I think you are overthinking this. Get rid of `none` and `noode` from your node class. Change `printInOrder(root->noode->data);` to `printInOrder(root);`

Comment: You seem (based on previous questions) to have some confusion between the names of parameters and the names of your member variables. The two are not connected (except that the former may *shadow* the latter).

Comment: I tried that but it traverses the tree inoderly but I want to traverse that of the preorder inoderly

Comment: I'm afraid I don't follow. If you have a method called `printInOrder` what would you want it to do except print in order. And what does 'traverse that of the preorder inoderly' mean?

Comment: As always it helps if you **show** the output you are expecting, instead of trying to describe what you are expecting. Less misunderstandings that way.

Answer (score 0):

Your code makes sense and works perfectly once you correct the parameter you pass into the printInOrder(); function, in your code you are trying to pass a value of type integer but the parameter specifies you need to pass type 'Node*' so instead of root->node->data you pass root and this will do exactly what you want.

```
        #include <stdio.h>
        #include <iostream>
        #include <queue>
        using namespace std;
        struct Node
        {
          string data;
          Node *left;
          Node *right;
          Node *none;
          Node *noode;
        };
        struct Node *createnode(string value)
        {
          Node *newnode = new Node;
          newnode->data = value;
          newnode->left = NULL;
          newnode->right = NULL;
          return newnode;
        }
        void printLevelOrder(Node *node)
        {
          if (node == NULL)
          {
            return;
          }

          queue <Node *> q;
          q.push(node);

          while (q.empty() == false)
          {
            Node *newnode = q.front();
            cout << newnode->data << " ";
            q.pop();

            if (newnode->left != NULL)
            {
              q.push(newnode->left);
            }

            if (newnode->right != NULL)
            {
              q.push(newnode->right);
            }
          }
        }

        void printPreOrder(Node *noode)
        {
          if (noode == NULL)
          {
            return;
          }

          cout << noode->data << " ";
          printPreOrder(noode->left);
          printPreOrder(noode->right);
        }
        void printInOrder(Node *none)
        {
          if (none == NULL)
          {
            return;
          }

          printInOrder(none->left);
          cout << none->data << " ";
          printInOrder(none->right);
        }

        int main()
        {
          struct Node *root = createnode("3");
          root->left = createnode("7");
          root->right = createnode("8");
          root->left->left = createnode("10");
          root->left->right = createnode("12");
          cout << "\nLevel Order Traversal:\n";
          printLevelOrder(root);
          cout << "\nPreOrder Traversal:\n";
          printPreOrder(root);
          cout << "\nInOrder Traversal:\n";
          printInOrder(root);
          return 0;
        }
```